# TwiML app doesn't send request

Tags: php, python, twilio, twilio-twiml

On my TwiML app, when I click the `call` button, the seconds start to count but nothing happens. I don't receive the request on my server, and I'm sure the url is correct.

Previously if something didn't work, I heard `Sorry, an application error has occurred`, but now I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest using the [error callback function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device) to see if the library is reporting a [specific error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/errors) back to you.

I believe we also output those error codes to the browser console as well, so I'd also suggest checking there.

Hope that helps.